# Finding a gaussian function fit

Tags: fitting

I have a series of data and I want to find the best gaussian fit.
As you can see in the notebook I imported, there is something wrong.

`Lin0005` is the series of data that I want to put on the y axis.
`DataX` is the table with the x coordinates to associate with Lin0005. 
`Data0005` is the matrix that puts `Lin0005` together with DataX.

`DataFit0005` should have the coordinates of the points of the gaussian function that best fits `Data0005`, but as you can see it is not. The values are all too close to zero and I don't understand why.

Can anyone help me?

```
Import["http://halirutan.github.io/Mathematica-SE-Tools/decode.m"]["https://i.stack.imgur.com/aesRB.png"]
```

Comment: Evidently I don't know how to import a notebook. I used SEUploader and copied the notebook link from the clipboard...

Comment: A question that appears to an exact duplicate of your question can be found  here [Why do my attempts to fit data to a Gaussian curve fail?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158742/why-do-my-attempts-to-fit-data-to-a-gaussian-curve-fail)

Comment: Another link that could be helpful is [Fitting 1D data to Gaussian, getting parameters](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/156793/fitting-1d-data-to-gaussian-getting-parameters/156805#156805)

Comment: Related: [158745](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158742/why-do-my-attempts-to-fit-data-to-a-gaussian-curve-fail/158745#158745)

Answer (score 2):

I cannot tell that I understood all you did in your notebook, such as the aim of the operation `DataFit0005=Table[{x, a*Exp[-(x - b)^2/2*c^2] /. fit0005}, {x, 0.825 - 64*1.65, 0.825 + 63*1.65}]`, for example.

However, you are very close to the solution. Your data does not go to zero at large values of x, but rather to a constant, which one can see just plotting the `Data0005`. For this reason one should add an off-set to parameters:

```
ff = FindFit[Data0005, a*Exp[-(x - b)^2/(2*c^2)] + d, {a, b, c, d}, x]

(*  {a -> 115., b -> 0.911, c -> 6.37, d -> 5.07}  *)
```

as can be inspected by direct plotting the data together with the function:

```
Show[{
  ListPlot[Data0005, PlotRange -> {0, 120}, PlotStyle -> Blue],
  Plot[(a*Exp[-(x - b)^2/(2*c^2)] + d) /. ff, {x, -100, 100}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red]
  }]
```

yielding the following:

[image]

Have fun!